# How to find $n_1+n_2+…+n_r$?

Tags: polynomials

There exist r unique no negative integers $n_1\gt n_2 \gt…\gt n_r$ and r unique integers $a_k(1\le k \le r)$ with each $a_k$ either 1 or -1 such that $$ a_1 3^{n_1}+ a_2 3^{n_2}+ a_33^{n_3}+…+ a_r 3^{n_r}=2022 $$
How to find the sum $n_1+n_2+…+n_r$?

Comment: Write 2022 in base-3 and compute all numbers

Comment: You can also try modulo-comparing powers of $3$ with $10$ and $10^2$, and see how the remainders are distributed. This should help you to get the desired value of $2022$

Comment: Hint: try to look at the first $8$ powers of $3$ and identify, which combinations of their remainders base $10$ can result in the total sum of $2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing successively by $3$ and leaving remainders we get:
$$2022=674\ 0=\\224\ 2\ 0=\\74\ 2\ 2\ 0=\\24\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 0=\\
8\ 0\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 0=\\2\ 2\ 0\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 0=\\
2\cdot 3^6+2\cdot 3^5+2\cdot 3^3+2\cdot 3^2+2\cdot 3$$

To convert the twos into ones and minus ones we notice that $$2\cdot3^n=3^{n+1}-3^n$$

Starting from the lowest power of three we convert to get
$$2\cdot 3^6+2\cdot 3^5+2\cdot 3^3+3\cdot 3^2+(-1)\cdot 3=\\
2\cdot 3^6+2\cdot 3^5+3^4-3=\\
3^7-3^5+3^4-3$$

Finally, we add the numbers to get $7+5+4+1=17$